# How do I use the value of a variable to do things in my code?

Tags: c++, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse an HTML file for a C++ assignment. The assignment is demonstrating stacks; we're supposed to push to the stack every time we hit a tag, and then pop off when we find the corresponding closing tag.

The teacher obviously wants us to hard-code a set of tags to detect, like:

```
// Declare some stacks
Stack html;
Stack div;
...

// When you find an open tag, push to the corresponding stack
if (tagcontents == "html") { html.push(); }
if (tagcontents == "div") { div.push(); }
...

// When you find a close tag, push to the corresponding stack
if (tagcontents == "/html") { html.pop(); }
if (tagcontents == "/div") { div.pop(); }
...
```

The obvious downside of this is that if I want to support [all of the tags available in HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp), I can expect to do lots of redundant coding. The teacher obviously wants us to pick just a small subset of the available tags, and go off those, but I think that's **lame**. Since I'm lazy (and I firmly believe that all programmers should be), I'm trying to come up with a dynamic solution.

The idea is, whenever I encounter a new tag, create a stack for it. This would allow my program to support ANY tag, regardless of validity. I'm hitting an interesting theoretical problem, though, and I'm not even sure what to call it in order to research it. Namely, that I need to use the VALUE of a variable as part of my actual code. IE:

```
if (no stack exists named "HTML") { create a stack named "HTML" }
```

In simplistic terms, how can I:

```
tag = "html";
Stack tag;  // make a stack named HTML?
```

Or is there another way to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I can't figure this out, I'll probably just use a switch/case statement like a quitter.

Answer (score 0):

Create the stacks inside a `std::map<std::string, Stack>`.

Answer (score 0):

use a map/unordered map:

`std::map <std:string, Stack> myStacks;`

Then you can just do

`myMastacks[tagcontents].push()`

This will initialize a new stack for the key if one does not yet exist.

and on the end of tag, strip the slash, check if it's on the map, and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently, more simple, with only one stack for all tags (which I think is very reasonable, unless your teacher actually instructed you to use several stacks): Declare a stack of strings. A string represents a tag. You can use the STL stack for this:

`stack<string> my_tags;`

`my_tags.push("div")` will push "div" into the stack.
`string tag = my_tags.top();` will query the top of the stack, and `my_tags.pop()` will pop the top item from the stack. Very easy :-)

Again, this solution is good in case you don't really need to practice several stacks, but to examine where you stand within the html parsing.

Comment: But this just tests for an equal amount of opening tags and close tags in the code, right? I need to throw errors on original tags. This is an interesting proposal, because AFAIK valid HTML requires all tags to be nested, and therefore you'd never have something like <div><p></div></p>. Hmm, I'll have to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::list<std::string> stack;
typedef std::map<std::string, stack> stack_map;

stack_map my_stacks;

stack& getStack(const std::string& stack_name) {
   stack_map::iterator it = my_stacks.find(stack_name);
   if( it != my_stacks.end() ) {
      return it->second;
   } else {
      my_stacks[stack_name] = stack();
      return my_stacks[stack_name];
   }
}


...
stack& div_stack = getStack("div");

// and use that for example
div_stack.push_back("some info");
div_stack.push_back("some more info ... ");
div_stack.push_back("s  even more ... ");

.....
```